# Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information) what is the reason of this error in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zblM.png)

When I click any video card this error occured it doesn't to */watch/dfdhd343* or When I click it doesn't goes to the Channel detail page */channel/2scxXE9ed*. This is the problem I am using latest reactjs and next js why this error is ocurred

Comment: You need to run the project locally (`npm run dev`) for you to get the error details

Comment: it doesn't give this error locally

Comment: For that particular case, Sentry can be super helpful in tracking production errors for you. You can set up Sentry for your project by following this [GUIDE](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/). Once you have setup Sentry, deploy the changes, then visit the URL again. Sentry will capture the error and send to your Sentry issues dashboard.